# RestKit HTTP response code without mapping

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm using RestKit to POST a new resource of which the server response is not important to me. I only need to know whether it was successful or not (HTTP 200 or not).

When I'm not setting any mapping for that resource I get `Expected status code in (400-499), got 200}` and the failure callback is called.

Is there any way to enable RestKit detect it's a successful respond without adding an unnecessary response descriptor mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have no mapping to do so you should be using RestKit to create the request to be sent and then dealing with sending it yourself. The purpose of RestKit making a request is to map the response so you will get an error if the response can not be mapped.

Comment: oh. And what RestKit method should I use to only create the request?

Comment: Look at `requestWithObject:method:path:parameters: `

Answer (score 0):

Try this

statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)